# Uninstalling Spatie Package in Laravel getting error Class 'Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I have uninstalled in Laravel 5.4 the Spatie package, whenever I try to load my application I get the error

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError Class
>
> 'Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider' not found
>
> in ProviderRepository.php line 208

Here is my composer.json contents

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.3",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3",
        "infyomlabs/adminlte-templates": "5.4.x-dev",
        "infyomlabs/laravel-generator": "5.4.x-dev",
        "infyomlabs/swagger-generator": "dev-master",
        "jlapp/swaggervel": "dev-master",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Here is my provider array in confi/app.php

```
 'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */
        Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class,
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
        Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider::class,
        Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class,
        \InfyOm\Generator\InfyOmGeneratorServiceProvider::class,
        \InfyOm\AdminLTETemplates\AdminLTETemplatesServiceProvider::class,
        Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class,
        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],
```

Comment: run `composer dumpautoload` or delete the config file

Comment: Thanks deleting config file did the trick

Comment: Which config file did you delete @BAKARISHEGHEMBE?

Comment: Goto bootstrap/cache folder and delete config.php